# Перебор узлов XML на Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, xml

Требуется из [этой XML](https://replit.com/@DanilaEpishev/GhostwhiteUltimateNumerators#xml_file) распарсить узлы и дочерние элементы в соответствии с их соотношением друг к другу. Схема сопоставления: `<s>IP-адрес</s>,<d>IP-адрес</d>,<dport>INT</dport>,<p>TCP/UDP</p>` Пример: ***10.11.11.1, 10.12.11.3, 465, TCP.*** Объяснение: ***(s=source,d=destination,dport=port,p=protocol) |*** На всякий случай, приложу ещё сам [iptables](https://replit.com/@DanilaEpishev/GhostwhiteUltimateNumerators#iptables). Делал через Python, но там в выводе получается мусор и они неравномерно распределяются - код ниже. Спасибо большое

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('1.xml', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as xml:
        soup = Soup(xml.read(), 'lxml')

    dport_tcp = [tcp.find('dport').text for tcp in soup.find_all('tcp')]
    dport_udp = [udp.find('dport').text for udp in soup.find_all('udp')]
    multport = [multiport.find('dports').text for multiport in soup.find_all('multiport')]
    ports = dport_tcp+dport_udp+multport
    #print(dport_tcp, dport_udp, sep='\n')
    source = [match.find('s') for match in soup.find_all('match')]
    destination = [match.find('d') for match in soup.find_all('match')]
    for match in soup.find_all('match'):
        if match.find('d') == 'None':
            print("error")
    print(destination)
```

Comment: Вы получили три списка ports, source и destination, а по какому принципу вы хотели их объединить в результирующий?

Comment: Чтобы оно выводило вот [такого](https://imgur.com/a/qJO0YNQ) формата, но в виде текста